# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)} \ dx$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus

> Show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)} \ dx$$ is convergent.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)} \ dx$$ is convergent by comparison test with $\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^4} dx$.

How do i show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)} \ dx$$ is convergent?

Comment: A simple observation: The degree of the numerator is 2 and of denominator is 6. In addition, the denominator does not have real zeros. Can you think of a suitable comparison function?

Comment: It looks to me you already answered your own question. If you do not fear the residue theorem, you can also check the integral exactly equals $\frac{7\pi}{50}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how has op answered his/her question? does comparison test work on $(-\infty,0]$ as well?

Comment: or do we substitute $u = -x$ first?

Answer (score 3):

Another way:
$$
0\le\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(\underbrace{(x+1)^2+1)}_{\ge 1}}\le\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\le\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+1} 
$$

Comment: Excellent, very fast ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you have:

$$1\geq 0 \Longrightarrow x^2+1\geq x^2\Longrightarrow \frac{x^{2}}{x^2+1}\leq 1$$

$$x^2\geq 0 \Longrightarrow 1+x^2\geq 1\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{x^2+1}\leq 1$$

multiplying both inequalities together we get

$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\leq 1$$

this implies ( by multiplying both sides by ${\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+2)}}$):

$$0\leq \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)}\leq \frac{1}{(x^2+2x+2)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$$

because $x^2+2x+2=(x+1)^2+1>0$

and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}}dx=\pi$$

Comment: Clean answer, but I would include something about how each of the relevant expressions are nonnegative also.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks

Comment: How do you extend the comparison test to the entire real line?

Comment: You can divide in two integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

Comment: How about the integral from $(-\infty , 0]$? Comparison test doesn't apply directly on that interval. Did you applied a change in variable first to change the limits of integrals to $[0,\infty)$?