# Show without calculating that $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 2x + 2)} dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Show **without** evuluating the integral that $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 2x + 2)} dx$ converges.

There is a similar question posted [Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)} \ dx$ is convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526854/show-that-int-infty-infty-dfracx2x212x22x2-dx-is-con) whereby nobody actually showed that the above integral is convergent without evaluating the integral.

Is it right that I first let $u = -x$, then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 2x + 2)} dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^2}{(u^2 + 1)^2(u^2 -2u + 2)} du$$

Afterwards I can apply the Comparison test on the Right hand side?

The only comparison test I know of is the one stated in Stewart's book,

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions with $f(x) \geq g(x) \geq 0$ for $x\geq a$. If $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is convergent, then $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) dx$ is convergent.
>
> If $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) dx$  is divergent, then $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is divergent.

Or what is the better approach here?

Comment: Try to make a bound with some constant times $1/x^4$ for $x>M$ for some $M>1$ and use comparison test.

Comment: @Shashi Comparison test works for integrals of the form $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ where $a\geq 0$ only?

Comment: The OP stated in his own question *is convergent by comparison test with*...

Comment: @LittleRookie no but you have only concerns with the tail.

Comment: @Shashi I was only given one version of comparison test, can you tell me more about it?

Comment: @Shashi I'm talking about negative infinity to 0 in my post.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Help please :(

Comment: @LittleRookie oh sorry I misunderstood you a little bit. You have made a substitutution, so that you have it in the same form as your theorem. I do not see your problem

Comment: And the minus sign shouldn't bother you, if your integral is positive from some $a>0$

Comment: @Shashi i can't find a suitable integral for comparison after the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

It's because if $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)}$, then$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{1/x^4}=1.$$

Comment: I presume you mean $1/x^4$?

Comment: @NicholasStull I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Only thing I might add is that in a neighborhood of $x=0$, the function is bounded (by $1$, if I'm not mistaken). +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)}$. We begin by looking for any singularities of $f$ in $(-\infty,0]$. Actually, there are none, as both the polynomials $x^2+1$  and $x^2+2x+2=0$ have negative discriminant. Hence the integral converges iff $f(x)$ decreases quickly enough as $x\to -\infty$. In particular, it suffices to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}f(x)dx$ converges. As you probably know,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx <\infty $$
Now notice that
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}|f(x)|x^2=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^2|x^2+2x+2|}=0 $$
This shows that the function $x\mapsto x^2|f(x)|$ is bounded on $(-\infty,-1]$, and hence there is a constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C\frac{1}{x^2}$ for all $x\in (-\infty,-1]$. Thus
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^{-1}f(x)dx\right|\leq\int_{-\infty}^{-1}|f(x)|dx\leq C\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx<\infty $$